# Statistics Proof that $E[(X-Y)^2] = 0$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, self-study

If X and Y are standardized variables and are perfectly positively correlated with respect to each other, how can i prove that $E[(X-Y)^2] = 0$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$E[(X-Y)^2) = E(X^2) + E(Y^2) - 2E(XY)$

Use the fact that $X, Y$ are standardized and perfectly correlated to make appropriate substitutions above to get the desired result.

PS: I am not providing the complete solution. Hopefully, the above hints will set you on the right path.

Comment: I know that E(XY) is 1 (this is the correlation), so E(X^2)+E(Y^2) must equal 2 but I'm having trouble showing this.

Comment: Can you connect E(X^2) to the variance formula?

Comment: Ahh so E(X^2) = Variance(X) when the mean is 0, and so variance is 1.